# Figures in ShareLatex

Tags: graphics

It seems like this question has been asked many times before, but none of the previous responses are working for me. I'm using ShareLatex.com, and I can't get figures to work correctly. I just get a blank box with the name of the figure, like this. [image] The figure is in the same folder as the .tex file. Any ideas what to do to fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,portrait]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics{cornering3031.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `portrait` option is nothing known to `article` or the used packages there. Especially your document is not compilable and after using a local `.jpg` file for my compilation tests I see the image and no frame with the filename. I suspect you have the `draft` option enabled. Try `\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,final]{article}`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! For me it works too. I agree with Christians suspection ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but unfortunately they didn't seem to work. I tried that document class, and I don't have the draft compile mode enabled. Looks the same...

Comment: Seems like it could be .png file type. I tried using a .jpg instead and it worked. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: are you using latex pr pdflatex? (latex+dvips can not include png (but it gives a warning in the log)

Comment: I'm using pdflatex

Comment: the output you show is the  output from draft mode but the example you post doesn't use draft, can you post the log file from that example?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you've forgotten to upload the image file or the filename doesn't exactly match. Here's a screenshot from ShareLaTeX:

[image: ShareLaTeX screenshot]

The bit I've circled shows that there are two messages. If you click on that area, it will show the messages:

[image: ShareLaTeX screenshot]

The message reads:

> File `cornering3031.png' not found.

So just make sure that the image file has been uploaded and that you've spelt it correctly.

You mentioned in the comments that it worked for a `.jpg` file but not for the `.png` file, so perhaps you only uploaded the `.jpg` file or the `.png` filename doesn't exactly match. (Have you uploaded the image from a case-insensitive system, such as Windows? Perhaps the case doesn't match. For example, the extension may actually be `.PNG` not `.png`.)